# How to estimate the effect of time series on a variable sampled irregularly and much less frequently for multiple subjects

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing, estimation, modeling, panel-data

I’ve been struggling for several days to find the proper statistical analysis tools for my problem, and I’m hoping for some valuable tips and insight from the internet. I’ve read up on ARIMA(X), Vector Auto-Regression, longitudinal data, panel analysis, etc., and while I feel that I am headed in the right direction, I cannot make sense of it all yet, and I don’t think I have found the proper method for handling my problem so far.

As this is outside of my subject area, I hope you’ll forgive me for my imprecise terminology in the following. I’ll be happy to clarify any questions that come up.

#### The problem:

For 100 different participants, we have health data (**A**) that is collected as a continuous time series (every 15 minutes over 7 days → approx. 700 equally-spaced points).

We hypothesize an effect of this health data on a different variable (**B**), which was measured at 8 random time points on each of 3 subsequent (of the previously mentioned 7) days. In essence, we have 24 not-equally-spaced data points on B for each of the 100 participants.

A sample dataset of one participant is plotted below. It may be important to note that the means of A (or B) are not identical between participants.

[image: Sample Data]

Another way of looking at it – if we discarded data A on the 4 days where NO measurements of B are available –would be that we have 3 sets of (96 data points A) & (8 data points B) for each of the 100 participants. However, I believe that the information contained in A on the off-days could potentially link to the values of B on the measurement days, which is why I’m not a fan of throwing out valuable data. (Of course, only the days before the measurement – the part of time series A occurring after the last measurement of B is irrelevant!)

#### The question:

How can I determine if A is statistically significant in predicting B? I have a grouping variable (C) that splits the 100 participants 60:40, and I’d hope for B to be sensitive to A in one group and not in the other.

*Bonus:*
For a significant number of participants, the data in B is not complete, i.e. some-few to nearly-all of the 24 points may be missing (possibly in such a way that they are not easily predicted/interpolated). It would be possible to throw this data out and only work with a set of participants for which all measurements are available, but I’d much prefer if a method was capable of dealing with cases where different amounts of data are available for each participant.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.